# Issue enabling jpa and jdbc in Websphere Liberty

Tags: jpa, jdbc, websphere-liberty

I am following these exercises for learning Liberty.

I am having an issue in he Lab 3 - Module 2.2 Liberty and JPA (DB2) .
 After setting all the JDBC and Data Source details, i restart the server and i do not see the two lines that mention the dataSource and jdbd driver.

[AUDIT] J2CA8004I : The dataSource DB2Connection is avilable as jdbc/DB2Connection.
 [AUDIT] J2CA8000I : The jdbcDriver my JDBCDriver is available.

How can i know if the jpa and jdb features ae correctly set?

This is the server.xml

```
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager onError="WARN">
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
              httpPort="9080"
              httpsPort="9443" />


<jdbcDriver id="myJDBCDriver">
    <library name="DB2Lib">
        <fileset dir="C:\wlp\db2jdbc" includes="db2jcc4.jar, db2jcc_license_cu.jar"></fileset>
    </library>
</jdbcDriver>
<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/DB2Connection" id="DB2Connection"
    jdbcDriverRef="myJDBCDriver">
    <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="SAMPLE" serverName="igacloud" password="{xor}FhgeOz1tPj08" user="db2admin"></properties.db2.jcc>
</dataSource>
```

Comment: Did you try to access that database? Does it give any exceptions? You might be missing `port` attribute, check this page http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-3-11-0-3-2-17-0-0&lang=en

Comment: I can connect without issues from Data Studio using the same parameters

Comment: Do you see any errors/exceptions or warnings in the log after adding these properties?

Comment: No. There are no errors in the log.
However, the features are enabled

[11/05/15 14:21:14:544 COT] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [servlet-3.0, jsp-2.2, jndi-1.0, localConnector-1.0, jdbc-4.0, beanValidation-1.0, jpa-2.0].

Comment: Did you actually write any code that would access that datasource? If you did you would either successfully connect or had some error in the logs. [AUDIT] message may not even appear in the logs, depending on logging level.

Comment: Not yet. I will try coding something tonight and let you know.

However, in the server, i set the logging to "INFO", and nothing related to JPA or JDBC appeared yet.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Classic WebSphere, which has a "test connection" capability in its admin console (datasource panel), there is no equivalent means with WebSphere Liberty yet.  Have you tried testing the connection with a simple "Hello World" JPA application?

The CWWKF0012I message is simply confirming what features have been enabled - some features depend on other features and automatically enables them, which is why you see more features than defined in your server.xml.